# Identify selected tab URL of firefox browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am working on one web application.
I am interested in to fetch selected tab URL. I am using Firefox browser.

I achieved this by executing below javascript statements :

```
/* Get the URL of page which is currently loaded in active tab  */
var currentPageURl = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
alert(currentPageURl);
```

Above statement work if page is loaded. But if I open's a new tab on Firefox browser (not entered any URL ) and executes above javascript. I am getting **about:blank** as a result.

I wanted to add such javascript statements which should handle such that if current page is loaded in tab then only gives URL, **if page is not loaded then it should return false instead of about:blank**

Your suggestions are welcome!!!

Thanks

-Pravin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&&` or an *if* statement to check the value:

```
// return false if about:blank, url if anything else
return currentPageURl != "about:blank" && currentPageURl;
```

Equivalent of

```
if (currentPageURl == "about:blank")
    return false;
else
    return currentPageURl;
```

Comment: this seems fine to me....but is there any boolean value returns from window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href; 
So that i can catch and validate accordingly instead of comapring with "about:blank" string. - BTW Thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: @pravin: Just `return currentPageURl != "about:blank"` would return a boolean.