# How to get the selected tab of the browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the selected tab of the browser using JavaScript?

Comment: I should certainly hope you can't. What I have in different tabs is hardly the business of the website in any one of them.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, cause :

**1.** there are browsers which do not even have tabs

**2.** browsers usually never let you access their tabs

Using a firefox addon you might be more successfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless they're internal tabs on your page.

Comment: Hi, actually they have given a solution in the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715956/identify-selected-tab-url-of-firefox-browser-in-javascript. but that doesn't work for me.Do you still think that it's not possible to get taburl ?

Comment: @gaurav: It seems that the OP developed some plugin for Firefox. That is why he has access to the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file name of the current tab but you can not select/switch the tab of the browser.